# Duplicating input validations at both API Gateway and Lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I imported an OpenAPI file into API Gateway to leverage the schema validations.

For example, I am trying to validate a phoneNumber in a request body:

```
// OpenAPI format
phoneNumber:
  type: string
  pattern: '^\d{10}$'
```

API Gateway throws a 400 bad request as expected if the input is bad. However, as I am parsing `APIGatewayProxyEvent` in a Lambda handler, I am not sure if I should duplicate the same validation in Lambda functions as a security measure. As follows:

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, Context, APIGatewayProxyResult } from "aws-lambda"

export async function handleEvent(event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> {
  
  if (event.body == null) {
    return {
      body: ..
      statusCode: 400
    }
  }
  const userInfo: UserInfo= JSON.parse(event.body);

  // Duplicate validation
  if (!isPhoneNumberValid(userInfo)) return {statusCode: 400, body: ..}; 

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: ..
  }
}

function isPhoneNumberValid(user: UserInfo): boolean {
  const phoneRegex: RegExp = '^\d{10}$';
  phoneRegex.test(user.phoneNumber);
}
```

I read that it is always good to not trust user input and validate in the backend. Does this rule also apply to API Gateway + Lambda set up? I had to add a specific IAM role policy for API Gateway to invoke Lambda, and I am not sure how a malicious user can bypass API Gateway to invoke Lambda directly.

Answer (score 1):

### A few reasons it might be a good idea:

**Catch Future Bugs**

Let's say you only have validation on that one layer, but it's good and correct now. It's certainly possible that at some point a year or more in the future, after you've written this and handed it off to the next person, or just forgotten about it, or the design changes, that validation might be removed. (For example, what if someone removes it because it doesn't handle international numbers, and the complexity of handling all those scenarios is too difficult, so it just gets removed.) Adding a second layer acts as a safeguard against accidental removal.

**Guard Against Unknown Flaws**

You are correct that you shouldn't trust user data - always validate it. Maybe the link between your Gateway and Lambda function are secure now. But software has bugs, and exploits may be discovered. Adding an extra safety check is a good idea if it can prevent potential security leaks.

**It's Cheap, Why Not?**

In this case, your validation is inexpensive to write, and the execution is trivial. All code has a cost to maintain, certainly. But in this situation it doesn't seem like much. It may be useful to document, either in your official documentation or a comment, that this validation occurs at two different locations. This would reduce any future maintenance cost.

**An Opportunity For Extra Validation**

OpenAPI provides a limited ruleset for validation of data; it can't cover all the different subtle rules. Maybe you want to make sure a phone number matches the user's country, for example. Your Lambda function can do a more in-depth validation here to ensure the user's input is correct.

### A few reasons it might be a bad idea:

**It's Unlikely To Provide Value**

You already have validation that rejects invalid input at the user-accessible layer. If an error occurs here, it's likely the result of a bigger issue happening. It's not likely duplicating this specific validation at another layer will provide significant value.

**All Code Has A Development/Maintenance Cost**

Unit tests covering valid and invalid values need to be written. The logic of limiting phone numbers to this specific format needs to be documented. No matter how simple your code, eventually someone will have to update or maintain it. All code has a cost, so doubling your code to repeat the same functionality increases your burden.

**It Doesn't Cover All Formats**

Different countries have different formats for phone numbers. What about country codes? What if someone's using an office number that requires an extension to reach them? What if someone uses a fake 555 number? It's likely to cause a lot of friction for users, so it's good to remove it.